# How can I use my language variables before foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, sorting, foreach

I would like to sort mysql results alphabetically. My mysql database storing the english variable, and I use this variable for translating to user language. (Language files are in flat php file). I would like to sort by the country names ( I already do this after the query, but it sorted by the english variables). How can I use the translated language variables before my foreach loop started? This is a codeigniter engine. I tried to use js to sorting, but it changed the structure of my result, and this is not good for me. I need some tutorial, or idea how can I use my language variables (because I would like to use variables before the foreach loop starting).

Comment: So you store you English texts in the database and the translations in flat php files? I would store everything in the database so that you can get it from the database, sorted correctly.

Comment: Yes. But I have categories table in the database which storing the country name variable, the id of category, etc.. If I would like to store all language variables I must add a new field for every language.

Comment: No, just add a translations table with an ID of the category, an ID of the language and the text. There you could store all languages including English.

Comment: Thats what I can not do, because lack of knowledge. I could add new fields to categories, and all existing tables, but if I add a new table then I must connect with the whole system and I can't do this.

Comment: I need an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out gettext, it's not too difficult to implement and really easy to work with once it's set up.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: thanks, but I have existing language files, and I think gettext needs to create new language files

Comment: If they all are in one format you could write a script to convert them to gettext format ;)